# why to define ros::spin() in another thread?

Tags: ros, thread, spinning, spin

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey all,

There is an example in actionlib tutorial: wiki.ros.org/actionlib_tutorials/Tutorials/SimpleActionClient(Threaded). In this example the ros::spin() command is used in another thread.
Why should I create a ros::spin() command in a new thread? Why shouldn't I use this command in the end of the main like  I see in the most of examples? What's the difference between these two cases?

Thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/193337/why-to-define-ros::spin()-in-another-thread?/) by [SHPOWER](https://answers.ros.org/users/2209/shpower/) on ROS Answers with karma: 302 on 2014-09-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is to show how you can integrate the client into a larger system. In contrast to the first example client which takes over your only thread. http://wiki.ros.org/actionlib_tutorials/Tutorials/SimpleActionClient

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2014-09-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0